# Vue composition api composable functions lifecycle

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I have two composable functions in setup of my component:

```
setup(props, context) {

const {product, getProduct} = useProduct();

const {label, getLabel} = useLabel(product);


onBeforeMount(async() => {
await getProduct(root.$route.params.productId);
}
```

Here is my Problem. I import the methods/ refs of the composable functions `useProduct` & `useLabel`. I retrieve the value of the specific product in "`onMounted`" but pass the ref inside the setup which is called before. So product in useLabel is undefined. How can I pass it right when "product" has a value and use `label` inside of setup? Or is there an other way to achieve this?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing `useLabel` code but the `label` should probably be a computed ref so it changes when the `product` is loaded

Comment: Because your product retrieval is async, you should use the async version of setup, or put a watcher on it.

Comment: thanks! :) It is vue 2 with composition api plugin so I can't use async setup. But how can I put a watcher on product or use it as a computed ref? So that I still can also use it in setup

Comment: Or would it be better to use promise / then instead of async?